# https for main domain and http for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

So i need very simple codes for .htaccess

I want to redirect all traffic to https in main domain and redirect all traffic to http in subdomain without WWW.

Right now i am using this code to redirect all traffic to https

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

So main domain should be like this: https://website.com

and subdomain should be like this: http://sub.website.com

I found many answers but very complicated, so need simple solution.

**EDITED**

Solution given by **anubhava** works great. Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

# maindomain -> https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(website\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# subdomain -> http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(sub\.website\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: works good with subdomain but my main domain redirecting to subdomain

Comment: Do you have other rules also, if yes then show full .htaccess by editing your question. Also try updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your solution **anubhava**. it works great. there was some catch problem but its working perfect. just what i was looking for. thanks again