# .htaccess, Redirect to HTTPS on main domain and to HTTP on subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

Now, I have the following code in my .htaccess file

```
# redirect to https www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)(builders-steps\.ru)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# redirect to http subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+\.builders-steps\.ru)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

and it's working fine but main domain is now available on both https and http but I need the main domain to work only on HTTPS.   Subdomain is working fine with the current code (only on HTTP).

Can you guys help me with advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https for main domain and http for subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287816/https-for-main-domain-and-http-for-subdomain)

Comment: unfortunately this solution doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it´s working. Cannot try code here.

> For rewriting All your main domain, try first redirecting the
>   subdomain if it´s informed (higher restrictive) and later, if it´s not
>   applied, you will check if for the main domain.

```
# redirect to http subdomain
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+\.builders-steps\.ru)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)(builders-steps\.ru)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.builders-steps.ru/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Alejandro, thank for your advice.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

It causes the mistake: "Too many redirections" and subdomain doesn't work at all.

The problem is how to rewrite code so that `http://builders-steps.ru` always redirects on `https://builders-steps.ru`
and at the same time `https://msk.builders-steps.ru` always redirects on `http://msk.builders-steps.ru`

Comment: this is the full htaccess file - https://app.box.com/s/ime4nctsn09zlniz7ax3tkzxvnae98if